# Paste subsequent values in excel with condition

Tags: excel

I have data in an Excel sheet as:

```
Column A         Column B
1                1
5                5
6                6   
50               50
..               51 
..               52
..               53 
1                1
5                2
6                6
50               50
..               51
..               52
..               53
very long list
```

I want to fill Column `B` corresponding to Column `A` as shown above that if cell `A` is not blank then cell `B` will have same value as `A` ..and if Cell `A` has value 50, then next blank rows in column `B` will have subsequent values after 50 ..

I tried to make formula

```
=IF(A2="",IF(A2=50,50,VALUE(A1)+1),A2)
```

and pasted in Cell `B2` and dragged but it is giving me  wrong results:

```
5
6
50
51
1
1
..
```

Can anyone please suggest? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes your data starts in row 2. Paste in `B2` and fill down.

```
=IFERROR(IF(A2<>"",A2,IF(OR(AND(A2=50,A3=""),B1>=50),1+B1,"")),"")
```

This works on your use case, but it's all kinds of kludgy so might not extend well to other cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply paste in `B2`

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),B1+1,A2)
```

and then copy the formula by dragging it down

Outcome:

```
A   B
---------
1   1
5   5
6   6
50  50
    51
    52
    53
1   1
5   5
6   6
50  50
    51
    52
    53
```

**Note:** it won't work for B1. You have to have enter a value in this cell manually.

Comment: It won't work if the dangling value in column A is something other than 50. The use case doesn't really make this requirement clear, but I think the OP's trial formula implies it.